# Issues with Swiperjs library testing in react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, swiper.js, ts-jest

Added Swiper (https://swiperjs.com/react) to my project and tried to set up tests for my component. But after trying different approaches I failed to find working config.

So my question would be, how to test react component with Swiper using Jest and @testing-library/react?

My `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    // preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
    transform: {
        // '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
        '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageReporters: ['lcov'],
    testRegex: '(.*(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$',
    testResultsProcessor: 'jest-sonar-reporter',
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
    setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/setup.ts'],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setupAfterEnv.ts'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        'swiper/react': '<rootDir>/node_modules/swiper/react/swiper-react.js',
    },
    testEnvironmentOptions: {
        url: 'http://localhost',
    },
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            isolatedModules: true,
        },
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!swiper|swiper/react|ssr-window|dom7)'],
};
```

My component:

```
import React, { VFC } from 'react';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide, SwiperProps } from 'swiper/react';

type GalleryImage = {
    src: string;
    altText?: string;
};

type Props = {
    gallery: GalleryImage[];
};

export const Gallery: VFC<Props> = ({
    gallery,
}) => {
    const settings: SwiperProps = {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        slidesPerGroup: 1,
    };

    if (!gallery?.length) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <Swiper {...settings}>
            {gallery?.map((item) => (
                <SwiperSlide key={item.src}>
                    <img src={item.src} alt={item.altText} />
                </SwiperSlide>
            ))}
        </Swiper>
    );
};
```

And my test file:

```
import React, { ComponentProps } from 'react';
import { cleanup, render } from '@testing-library/react';

import { Gallery } from '../';

type GalleryProps = ComponentProps<typeof Gallery>;

const props: GalleryProps = {
    gallery: [
        { src: 'image1', altText: 'image no. 1' },
        { src: 'image2', altText: 'image no. 2' },
        { src: 'image3', altText: 'image no. 3' },
    ],
};

describe('<Gallery/>', () => {
    afterEach(cleanup);

    it('handles empty gallery', () => {
        expect(render(<Gallery gallery={[]} />).container).toBeEmptyDOMElement();
    });

    describe('when in Desktop view', () => {
        it('should show current image in slider', () => {
            render(<Gallery {...props} />);
        });
    });
});
```

After runnning a test I receive an error:

```
(0 , dom_js_1.default)(...).children is not a function
TypeError: (0 , dom_js_1.default)(...).children is not a function
    at getWrapper (/home/x/projects/styleguide/node_modules/swiper/core/core.js:473:23)
    at Swiper.Object.<anonymous>.Swiper.mount (/home/x/projects/styleguide/node_modules/swiper/core/core.js:480:22)
    at Swiper.Object.<anonymous>.Swiper.init (/home/x/projects/styleguide/node_modules/swiper/core/core.js:510:28)
    at mountSwiper (/home/x/projects/styleguide/node_modules/swiper/components-shared/mount-swiper.js:30:10)...
```

**Reproducable example can be found here: https://github.com/augustas2/swiper-test**

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi John, hope you are doing well. Did you manage to fix your issue somehow? Could you please share the solution? i happen to have the same one.